# Should I mention my program change on my resume?

Tags: resume, background-check, education

I am currently adjusting my resume to a position that I hope to work towards over the upcoming school year.

I had spent two years in one program and then over this summer I decided to change my program. I was wondering for the resume that I plan to submit, should I add my previous program?

I personally think that it should be on there, as I have not yet done any classes in my new program. I am worried that they may ask what I have learned, when there is really nothing to talk about.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely reflect an accurate position - that you are now studying towards outcome b) having previously being working towards outcome a).

As you say otherwise you risk being asked about something you have very little knowledge of yet!